# Error with a leaderboard setup in Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I tried to create a Leaderboard using the following code however it doesn't seem to want to accept this part:

```
StatCheck.find({serverID: message.guild.id}).sort([[userStats.level, 'descending']]).exec((err, res) => { ... }
```

This is what StatCheck is bound to:

```js
const { StatCheck } = require('./member_stats.json');
```

"member_stats.json" is the file I use to store XP and levels for each user.

```js
if(command === '!leaderboard'){
  message.delete();
  if (message.channel.id === "876597275856601168"){
    client.channels.cache.get({serverID: message.guild.id}).sort([[userStats.level, 'descending']]).exec((err, res) => {
      if(err) console.log(err);

      let.embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("XP Leaderboard")


      if(res.length === 0){  //no results
       embed.setColor("#FF0000")
       embed.addFields("ERROR", "No data found!")
      }else if (res.length < 10){  //<10 results
       embed.setColor("#8F00FF")
       for(i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
         let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(res[i].userid) || "Former Member"
         if(member === "Former Member"){
       embed.addFields(`${i+1}. ${member}`, `Level: ${res[i].level}`)
         } else{
       embed.addFields(`${i+1}. ${member.user.username}`, `Level: ${res[i].level}`)
         }
       }
      } else{  //10+ results
        embed.setColor("#8F00FF")
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
          let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(res[i].userid) || "Former Member"
          if(member === "Former Member"){
        embed.addFields(`${i+1}. ${member}`, `Level: ${res[i].level}`)
          } else{
        embed.addFields(`${i+1}. ${member.user.username}`, `Level: ${res[i].level}`)
          }
        }
      }
    message.channel.send(embed)
    })
    }
  }
       embed.setColor("#8F00FF")
                for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(res[i].userid) || "Former Member"
                    if(member === "Former Member") {
                        embed.addFields(`${i+1}. ${member}`, `Level: ${res[i].level}`)
                    } else {
                        embed.addFields(`${i+1}. ${member.user.username}`, `Level: ${res[i].level}`)
                    }
                }
            }
            message.channel.send(embed)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it throw an error or something? How is the `StatCheck` related to the code below?

Comment: The StatCheck was used instead of "client" in `client.channels.cache.get({serverID: message.guild.id}).sort([[userStats.level, 'descending']]).exec((err, res) => {` However that gave out the following error; `cannot read property channels of undefined.`

Comment: Update: I've tried numerous different things for the code along with the lines of changing "StatCheck" and `  client.channels.cache.get({serverID: message.guild.id}).sort([[userStats.level, 'descending']]).exec((err, res) => {` but the sorting function just won't function and keeps returning the error of `cannot read property channels of undefined.`